# How to terminate a loop after user enters a sentinel value?

Tags: c, loops

The following code is calculating the average of three exams for any given amount of students.
My problem is that I keep getting a runtime error. I cannot figure out how to make the "any Students" part stop after the user has entered a sentinel number, which is -1.
I am wondering what I am doing wrong or what am I missing?

**My Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main () { 
    /* variable definition: */ 
    char StudentName[100]; 
    char done= -1;
    float ExamValue, Sum, Avg; 
    int students,exams;
    int max = INT_MAX;
    // Loop through any Students 
    for (students=0; students < max && StudentName != done; students++) 
    { 
        // reset Sum to 0 
        Sum =0.0; 
        printf("Enter Student Name and then -1 after the last student \n"); 
        scanf("%s", StudentName); 
        if (StudentName == done)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        // Nested Loop for Exams 
        for (exams=0; exams < 3; exams++) 
        { 
            printf ("Enter exam grade: \n"); 
            scanf("%f", &ExamValue); 
            Sum += ExamValue; 
        } 
        Avg = Sum/3.0; 
        printf( "Average for %s is %f\n",StudentName,Avg); 

    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *stcmpr* function for comparing chars !! it returns 0 if equal !

Comment: Thank you so much! That was it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
    if (StudentName == done)
The predicate you are testing is comparing a char with an adress, which is not gonna have the expected result.
done is a char, and StudentName a char array, those two objects are different, since StudentName[0] is a char, but StudentName represents the adress of StudentName[0].

So i'd advice you to try

```
if(atoi(StudentName) == -1)
```

It should have the expected behaviour, and this way you don't need the `done` variable anymore.

Comment: You cannot compare a string against a plain `char`.

Comment: this is UB because `&done` is not a pointer to a **null-terminating** char array

Comment: better. I retracted the downvote. For my upvote: making `done` `char` make no sense. So either make `done` `int` or even better suggest comparing `StudentName` with `"-1"` (maybe make `done` a `char[]`).

Comment: umm... I am actually against magic numbers. So a (const) variable actually not the worst idea here. But this is nitpicking... You deserve my upvote for the willingness to improve your answer.